# What is the fastest way to compute an RBF kernel in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to compute an RBF or "Gaussian" kernel for a data matrix `X` with `n` rows and `d` columns. The resulting square kernel matrix is given by:

```
K[i,j] = var * exp(-gamma * ||X[i] - X[j]||^2)
```

`var` and `gamma` are scalars.

What is the fastest way to do this in python?

Comment: Are `var` and `gamma` scalars?

Comment: You might want to offer some up some test data here if performance is the main concern - otherwise it is tricky for anyone else to offer alternative solutions and compare them appropriately.

Comment: @Divakar yes, they are, I'll add that to the question. Thank you for pointing me to tis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well you are doing a lot of optimizations in your [`answer post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47271663/3293881). I would like to add few more (mostly tweaks). I would build upon the winner from the answer post, which seems to be `numexpr` based on.

#### Tweak #1

First off, `np.sum(X ** 2, axis = -1)` could be optimized with `np.einsum`. Though this part isn't the biggest overhead, but optimization of any sort won't hurt. So, that summation could be expressed as -

```
X_norm = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',X,X)
```

#### Tweak #2

Secondly, we could leverage Scipy supported blas functions and if allowed use single-precision dtype for noticeable performance improvement over its double precision one. Hence, `np.dot(X, X.T)` could be computed with [`SciPy's sgemm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.blas.sgemm.html) like so -

```
sgemm(alpha=1.0, a=X, b=X, trans_b=True)
```

Few more tweaks on rearranging the negative sign with `gamma` lets us feed more to `sgemm`. Also, we would push in `gamma` into the `alpha` term.

#### Tweaked implementations

Thus, with these two optimizations, we would have two more *variants* (if I could put it that way) of the `numexpr` method, listed below -

```
from scipy.linalg.blas import sgemm

def app1(X, gamma, var):
    X_norm = -np.einsum('ij,ij->i',X,X)
    return ne.evaluate('v * exp(g * (A + B + 2 * C))', {\
        'A' : X_norm[:,None],\
        'B' : X_norm[None,:],\
        'C' : np.dot(X, X.T),\
        'g' : gamma,\
        'v' : var\
    })

def app2(X, gamma, var):
    X_norm = -gamma*np.einsum('ij,ij->i',X,X)
    return ne.evaluate('v * exp(A + B + C)', {\
        'A' : X_norm[:,None],\
        'B' : X_norm[None,:],\
        'C' : sgemm(alpha=2.0*gamma, a=X, b=X, trans_b=True),\
        'g' : gamma,\
        'v' : var\
    })
```

#### Runtime test

Numexpr based one from your answer post -

```
def app0(X, gamma, var):
    X_norm = np.sum(X ** 2, axis = -1)
    return ne.evaluate('v * exp(-g * (A + B - 2 * C))', {
            'A' : X_norm[:,None],
            'B' : X_norm[None,:],
            'C' : np.dot(X, X.T),
            'g' : gamma,
            'v' : var
    })
```

Timings and verification -

```
In [165]: # Setup
     ...: X = np.random.randn(10000, 512)
     ...: gamma = 0.01
     ...: var = 5.0

In [166]: %timeit app0(X, gamma, var)
     ...: %timeit app1(X, gamma, var)
     ...: %timeit app2(X, gamma, var)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.25 s per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 1.24 s per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 973 ms per loop

In [167]: np.allclose(app0(X, gamma, var), app1(X, gamma, var))
Out[167]: True

In [168]: np.allclose(app0(X, gamma, var), app2(X, gamma, var))
Out[168]: True
```

Comment: Great! With my test setup, your variant #2 computes the kernel in 4.82 seconds, which is significantly faster than my 8.89 seconds. I'll wait 2 days to see if someone can come up with an even faster solution, but otherwise this will be the correct answer.

Comment: @Callidior Slightly tweaked app#2 a bit more. If you are timing, please use the updated one.

Comment: @Callidior Also, there's a very closely related project I was involved with sometime back - https://github.com/droyed/eucl_dist/wiki/Main-Article. I got amazing speedups with GPU. So, if you are really desperate for performance, I would highly recommend porting over to GPUs.

Comment: I get 4.7 s with the new version. However, how do you justify the use of single precision? Since the other methods would also be faster with single precision, I would normally consider that kind of cheating. Anyway, even with `dgemm` instead of `sgemm` your version is slightly faster than mine (8.28 s vs. 8.89 s).

Comment: @Callidior That's why I qualified it in the post as - `if allowed use single-precision dtype`, the subtext being if the use-case allows it. As also mentioned, it was stated to be noticeably faster than double precision one `dgemm`, which as you just saw is noticeably slower.

Comment: @Callidior I haven't seen `np.dot` allowing single precision. Would had been awesome though :) Or if you could figure that out.

Comment: If the two arguments to `np.dot` have a `dtype` of `np.float32`, the result is single precision as well and the computation is also faster. It hence seems to support single precision dot products.

Comment: @Callidior Ah yeah, that's one way! I guess I was worried about memory efficiency. So, then both `app0` and `app1` move forward with better timings.

Answer (score 22):

I am going to present four different methods for computing such a kernel, followed by a comparison of their run-time.

## Using pure numpy

Here, I use the fact that `||x-y||^2 = ||x||^2 + ||y||^2 - 2 * x^T * y`.

```py
import numpy as np

X_norm = np.sum(X ** 2, axis = -1)
K = var * np.exp(-gamma * (X_norm[:,None] + X_norm[None,:] - 2 * np.dot(X, X.T)))
```

## Using numexpr

[`numexpr`](http://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html) is a python package that allows for efficient and parallelized array operations on numpy arrays. We can use it as follows to perform the same computation as above:

```py
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne

X_norm = np.sum(X ** 2, axis = -1)
K = ne.evaluate('v * exp(-g * (A + B - 2 * C))', {
        'A' : X_norm[:,None],
        'B' : X_norm[None,:],
        'C' : np.dot(X, X.T),
        'g' : gamma,
        'v' : var
})
```

## Using `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`

We could also use [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) to compute a non-redundant array of pairwise squared euclidean distances, compute the kernel on that array and then transform it to a square matrix:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

K = squareform(var * np.exp(-gamma * pdist(X, 'sqeuclidean')))
K[np.arange(K.shape[0]), np.arange(K.shape[1])] = var
```

## Using `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.rbf_kernel`

`sklearn` provides a [built-in method](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.rbf_kernel.html) for direct computation of an RBF kernel:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import rbf_kernel

K = var * rbf_kernel(X, gamma = gamma)
```

## Run-time comparison

I use 25,000 random samples of 512 dimensions for testing and perform experiments on an Intel Core i7-7700HQ (4 cores @ 2.8 GHz). More precisely:

```py
X = np.random.randn(25000, 512)
gamma = 0.01
var = 5.0
```

Each method is run 7 times and the mean and standard deviation of the time per execution is reported.

```
|               Method                |       Time        |
|-------------------------------------|-------------------|
| numpy                               | 24.2 s ± 1.06 s   |
| numexpr                             | 8.89 s ± 314 ms   |
| scipy.spatial.distance.pdist        | 2min 59s ± 312 ms |
| sklearn.metrics.pairwise.rbf_kernel | 13.9 s ± 757 ms   |
```

First of all, `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` is surprisingly slow.

`numexpr` is almost 3 times faster than the pure `numpy` method, but this speed-up factor will vary with the number of available CPUs.

`sklearn.metrics.pairwise.rbf_kernel` is not the fastest way, but only a bit slower than `numexpr`.

Comment: So, what was the shape of the input(s) for the test setup? Was it 25000 x 512 for `X`?

Comment: @Divakar exactly.

Comment: Could you add the test setup, so that we could grab those from here and test out rather than we assume things?

Comment: @Divakar I've added you I generated the data, as well as `gamma` and `var`. I simply used the `%%timeit` magic from IPython for the measurements. I'm curious whether anyone gets to different findings.

Answer (score 1):

In the case that you are evaluating X against a high number of gammas, it is useful to save the negative pairwise distances matrix using the tricks done by @Callidior and @Divakar.

```
from numpy import exp, matmul, power, einsum, dot
from scipy.linalg.blas import sgemm
from numexpr import evaluate

def pdist2(X):
    X_norm = - einsum('ij,ij->i', X, X)
    return evaluate('A + B + C', {
        'A' : X_norm[:,None],
        'B' : X_norm[None,:],
        'C' : sgemm(alpha=2.0, a=X, b=X, trans_b=True),
    })

pairwise_distance_matrix = pdist2(X)
```

Then, the best solution would be to use `numexpr` to compute the exponential.

```
def rbf_kernel2(gamma, p_matrix):
    return evaluate('exp(g * m)', {
        'm' : p_matrix,
        'g' : gamma,
    })
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1001)
X= np.random.rand(1001, 5).astype('float32')
p_matrix_test = pdist2(X)
gamma_test_list = (10 ** np.linspace(-2, 1, 11)).astype('float32')

def app2(gamma, X):
    X_norm = - gamma * einsum('ij,ij->i', X, X)
    return evaluate('exp(A + B + C)', {\
        'A' : X_norm[:, None],\
        'B' : X_norm[None, :],\
        'C' : sgemm(alpha=2.0*gamma, a=X, b=X, trans_b=True),\
        'g' : gamma,
    })
```

I have the results:

```
%timeit y = [app2(gamma_test, x_test) for gamma_test in gamma_test_list]
```

> 70.8 ms ± 5.06 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

```
%timeit y = [rbf_kernel2(gamma_test, p_matrix_test) for gamma_test in gamma_test_list]
```

> 33.6 ms ± 2.33 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Note that you need to add the overhead to compute the pairwise distance matrix before but it shouldn't be much if you are evaluating against a large number of gammas.

Answer (score 0):

The NumPy solution with a given X, Y and gamma would be:

```
import numpy as np

def rbf_kernel(X, Y, gamma):
    X_norm = np.sum(X ** 2, axis=-1)
    Y_norm = np.sum(Y ** 2, axis=-1)
    K = np.exp(-gamma * (X_norm[:, None] + Y_norm[None, :] - 2 * np.dot(X, Y.T)))
    return K
```